# Skyrim working slow on 360 - if I install will I lose my progress?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Just like the title says, my wait times are starting to grind on me.  I want to try installing to the hard drive, but if I do this, will I still be able to continue on , or will I lose my progress? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your game files and your save data are two separate things.  Your save files are already on your Xbox, your game is not.  Installing it to the hard drive merely makes it less intensive for your system to run. You are not changing anything about your save files except how the system interacts between Skyrim and your save files.

So, in essence, nothing at all will even happen to your save files because they don't even have to be moved.

Answer (score 2):

You will not lose your progress by installing your disc copy onto the HDD.